# Как выполнить вычисление и сохранение результата в бд?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Всего есть 6 полей в бд, например нужно ввести два значения в поле `S_interval` и поле `M_interval`, а перед сохранение выполнить сложение и сохранить в бд результат в поле `Residue`. Подскажите пожалуйста как это сделать и где и на каком этапе в принципе это должно происходить? Очень благодарю, Заранее!

**Вот эти поля**

```
public class SPIAM
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Element { get; set; }
    public string Operatio { get; set; }
    public int S_interval { get; set; }
    public int M_interval { get; set; }
    public int Last { get; set; }
    public int Residue { get; set; }
}
```

**Вот контроллер**

```
public ViewResult CreateSPIAM()
{
    return View(new SPIAM());
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult CreateSPIAM(SPIAM spiam)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        repository.SaveSPIAM(spiam);
        TempData["message"] = string.Format(" \"{0}\" сохранен.", spiam.Element);
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
    else
    {
        return View(spiam);
    }
}
```

**Вот так сохраняю**

```
public void SaveSPIAM(SPIAM spiam)
{
    if (spiam.ID == 0)
        context.SPIAMS.Add(spiam);
    else
    {
        SPIAM dbEntry = context.SPIAMS.Find(spiam.ID);
        if (dbEntry != null)
        {
            dbEntry.Element = spiam.Element;
            dbEntry.Operatio = spiam.Operatio;
            dbEntry.S_interval = spiam.S_interval;
            dbEntry.M_interval = spiam.M_interval;
            dbEntry.Last = spiam.Last;
            dbEntry.Residue = spiam.Residue;
        }
    }
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

**Вот где ввожу данные**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.EditorForModel()
    <input type="submit" value="Сохранить" />
    @Html.ActionLink("Отменить", "Index", "Home")
}
```

Comment: Я так и не понял, у вас одно свойство зависит от значения других?

Comment: Я только учусь.. Делал многое по примерам и все было хорошо пока просто нужно вводить данные с формы и сохранять их в бд. Я думаю ответ на ваш вопрос - да. Я просто не понимаю как производить арифметические выражения и сохранять результат в бд, а главное где их производить?

Comment: Если у вас одно из свойств выражается через другие, причем зависимость не сложная, имеет смысл его вообще не хранить в БД, а вычислять "на лету": `public int C => A + B;` В этом случае вам вообще не придется беспокоиться о его сохранении и нужном моменте для расчета, но самое главное - вам не придется беспокоиться о том, чтобы при внесении изменений логика C=A+B не нарушилась

Comment: Я вас понимаю. Хранить значения нужно в любом случае. Тогда как и где сначала произвести расчет? Можете на моем примере показать?

Comment: тогда опишите подробнее какое свойство от каких зависит и по какому закону.

Comment: `dbEntry.Residue = spiam.S_interval + spiam.M_interval`

Comment: @WebMorda, в таком случае в в экземпляре `spiam` останется неправильное значение в свойстве `Residue`, не так ли?

Comment: @Андрей, если перед сохранением изменили `S_interval` и `spiam.M_interval`, тогда свойство `Residue` становится ложным.